# PageReference redirecting to wrong url

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

I have a force.com site with custom url for my web2lead just say **www.company.com/step1**. i want redirect it to **www.company.com/step2** after button clicked but it redirecting to **www.company.com/step1/step2**.

here's my PageReference

```
public PageReference Next(){ 
web2lead.Name = firstName+' '+lastName;
web2lead.Phone__c = phone;
web2lead.City__c = city;
web2lead.Company__c ='Keluarga '+firstName+' '+lastName;
web2lead.Email__c = email;
insert web2lead;

web2leadId = web2lead.Id;

PageReference step2Form = new PageReference('/step2');
step2Form.getParameters().put('id',web2lead.Id);
step2Form.setRedirect(true);
return step2Form;
}
```

did i doing something wrong ? because i don't want to put full url to PageReference like `PageReference('http://www.company.com/step2');`. can i do that ?

Comment: Could you try `PageReference step2Form = new PageReference('step2');`?

Comment: can you try PageReference step2Form = new PageReference ('/apex/step2'); ??

Comment: @Poet try using it but not working bro.

Comment: @FebrianTarigan This might be a bit of a stretch, but try `PageReference step2Form = new PageReference('../step2');` Normally what the `../` does is goes back a level in most languages I've used.

Comment: still not working. get redirect to `www.company.com/step1/step1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have suggested that you don't want to hard code the full URL like `http://www.company.com/step2`. In this case you can get the full URL dynamically with `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` and append the vf page name with it. I tried with the below solution and it is working as expected. Please try and let me know if this works.

step1 vf page

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectTestController"  >
    Hello World {!baseUrl}
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" value="Step2"/>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

step2 vf page

```
<apex:page >
    Hello World
</apex:page
```

Controller

```
public class RedirectTestController {
    public String baseUrl;
    public String getBaseUrl() {
        baseUrl=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        return baseUrl;
    } 
    public PageReference Next(){ 
        String nextpageurl = getBaseUrl() +'/step2';
        PageReference step2Form = new PageReference(nextpageurl);
        step2Form.setRedirect(true);
        return step2Form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate PageReference approach **`Page.Page_API_Name`** as:

```
PageReference step2Form = Page.step2; // Return pagereference Page.Page_API_Name
step2Form.getParameters().put('id',web2lead.Id);
step2Form.setRedirect(true);
return step2Form;
```

Comment: did it will be problem i use on force.com site ?

Comment: I believe it should automatically generate correct url which can work on site as well. @FebrianTarigan

Comment: it didn't work too. get redirect to `www.compay.com/step1/step2`